discord oauth2 login in laravel
im trying make a discord oauth login in my laravel project but its always returning error
get to solve this and my code
            $clientSecret = 'myclientsecret';
            $clientId = 'myclientid';
            $redirectUri = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/discord-auth';

            $tokenUrl = 'https://discord.com/api/oauth2/token';

            $data = [
                'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
                'client_id' => $clientId,
                'client_secret' => $clientSecret,
                'redirect_uri' => $redirectUri,
                'code' => $code,
                'scope' => 'identify%20guids',
            ];

            $res = Http::withoutVerifying()
                ->withHeaders([
                    'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                ])->post($tokenUrl, $data);

            dd($res);


im getting " Bad request " message

As a note, if you're okay with relying on a library, https://socialiteproviders.com/Discord could help simplify a lot of the internal stuff

is it possible to get a example in the package?
